# Drupal 6 - Redirect after add taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

When adding a taxonomy term in Drupal, it redirects back to itself to add another term. Is there a way of overriding this?

I have so far tried:

• Adding ?destination=_ to the page that links to the /add/term/ page
• Tried hook_taxonomy:

```
function modulename_taxonomy($op, $type, $array = NULL) {
  if ($type == 'term' && ($op == 'insert' || $op == 'update') && $array['parent'][39] == 39) {
    drupal_goto('page.html');
  }
}
```

If instead of `drupal_goto()` I put `die('Here');` it outputs, but the `drupal_goto()` does not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) one of the following ways.

- If you know in advance where you would like to be redirected, change the [`$form['#redirect']`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#redirect) entry.
- If you only know after submission where would like to be redirected, add an additional callback to [`$form['#submit']`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#submit-prop). That callback receives the `$form` array and the `&$form_state` array reference. Set the `$form_state['redirect']` entry to he path that you want to redirect to.

Comment: $form['#redirect'] didn't work so I altered $form['destination'] and now it is redirecting back to where I want it to. Thank you!

Comment: You can use $form_state['redirect'] - which is the replacement for $form['#redirect']

Answer (score 0):

You can use rules module, and i'm sure you can create an action to redirect to an URL.